# How to show numeric software keyboard on Android Tv?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-tv

I am trying to show numeric software keyboard on Android Tv when edittext is focused.

I have already tried these;

```
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);

editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

editText.setRawInputType(Configuration.KEYBOARD_12KEY);

android:inputType="phone"

android:inputType="number"
```

but they only disable text characters, don't make them invisible.

Is there a way to show phone type software keyboard on Android Tv?

Comment: What keyboard are you using?

Comment: separate keyboard or default android keyboard ?

Comment: sorry i forgot to explain, i'm talking about android software keyboard

Comment: I don't believe you can show a numeric keyboard on the TV itself. It's not part of the Leanback Keyboard.

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score -2):

You can check out [Input Method Editor](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) on the Android TV developer site. It has a sample there for [SoftKeyboard](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/SoftKeyboard/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Your links are for Android, not Android TV specific, and `android:inputType="phone"` is not working on Android TV